# How do you ensure .Net always searches for a namespace from the root of the namespace tree?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Is there a way to tell .Net to search for a namespace from the *root* of the namespace tree?

Say I have these two, completely independent, namespaces:

```
Apple.Orange.Banana
Orange.Grape.Peach
```

Assume they came from different programmers and the "Orange" in each one is completely coincidental.

If I'm inside "Apple.Orange.Banana" and I trying to import (or reference) "Orange.Grape.Peach," .Net things I'm trying to search from the "Orange" in "Apple.Orange.Banana".

How do I tell it, "Look from the *root*, not where I'm at now."  This would be great:

```
~Orange.Grape.Peach
```

But, alas, that doesn't exist.

I know that some of you will say I should just plan namespaces better, but what happens when I'm using code from two places that come with namespaces predefined that I cannot change, and they conflict as I've noted above?

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't exist? See Scott's answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using the global:: resolution scope? For example, if you have the following:

```
private global::Orange.Grape.Peach.classname x;
```

Also, you get different resolution depending on whether namespaces are imported outside of a namespace declaration or inside, so

```
using System.Linq;
namespace MyLinq 
{
   // ...
}
```

can provide different resolution rules than:

```
namespace MyLinq 
{
   using System.Linq;

   // ...
}
```

Comment: @Deane: You're welcome. Glad you were able to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could alias the root Orange like this:

```
using RootOrange = Orange;
```

Then you can do:

```
RootOrange.Grape.Peach
```